# What is the maximum number of regions into which a plane can be divided by fifteen lines given four of them are parallel?

Tags: combinatorics

This question was asked in exercise on combinatorics. I don't know how to approach this question logically as I don't think a brute force based counting method will yield me an answer.

Comment: Do you know how to do it if it is not required that some lines be parallel?

Comment: no, I don't know the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the maximum number of regions when the lines are generally positioned, that is, when no two lines are parallel, and no three meet in a point. Let's do that case first.

Let $r_n$ e the maximum number of regions formed by $n$ lines.  When we add the next line, it intersects the old lines in $n$ distinct points, by assumption, and these divide the new lines into $n+1$ segments.  Each of these segments divides some existing region in two, so we have $$r_{n+1}=r_n+n+1.\tag1$$
We have the initial condition $r_0=1$.  Solving $(1)$ gives $$r_n=\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}.$$
In the given problem, we take the first $12$ lines to be generally positioned, giving $r_{12}=79$ regions.

Can you modify the reasoning above to see how many regions are created when we add $3$ lines parallel to one of the first $12$?

Answer (score 1):

Parallel lines to one of n lines not parallel create n new regions.
For example if n=2, then when adding a parallel line to one of the two lines not parallel   means that two new regions are created. Originally two crossing lines creates 4 regions so when added to the 4 this means that there are a total of 6 regions. If three parallel lines are added instead of 1 parallel line, the number of additional regions is 3x2 or 6 new regions +4 original =10 total regions. By induction, Adding 3 parallel lines parallel to one of n parallel lines adds 3n in general to the number of regions. Therefore, if n=12 the total number of regions is 79+36=115.